# How to consum the kafka data once and deal with serveral SQL in structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark

I am a beginning of structured streaming. Currently, There are huge data in kafka. And we want to deal these data with serveral SQLs then output the result to different file.

I want to just consume the data once and then deal it.

```
 dataset.registerTempTable("netstream_bgp_result_6600");
        // for (int index = 0; index < 15; index++) {
        //
        // //
        // // datasets.add(result);
        // }

        for (int index = 0; index < 15; index++) {
            sparkSession.sql(SQLS.get(index))
                .writeStream()
                .format("console")
                .option("queryName", "qu" + (index++))
                .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
                .outputMode("complete")
                .start();
        }
```

But I got an error as following.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Set(struts-streaming-seconds-17, struts-streaming-seconds-16) are gone. Kafka option 'kafka.group.id' has been set on this query, it is
 not recommended to set this option. This option is unsafe to use since multiple concurrent
 queries or sources using the same group id will interfere with each other as they are part
 of the same consumer group. Restarted queries may also suffer interference from the
 previous run having the same group id. The user should have only one query per group id,
 and/or set the option 'kafka.session.timeout.ms' to be very small so that the Kafka
 consumers from the previous query are marked dead by the Kafka group coordinator before the
 restarted query starts running.
    . 
Some data may have been lost because they are not available in Kafka any more; either the
 data was aged out by Kafka or the topic may have been deleted before all the data in the
 topic was processed. If you don't want your streaming query to fail on such cases, set the
 source option "failOnDataLoss" to "false".
```

Comment: Anyone knows that how to read the data once from kafka and deal it with different SQL in spark structured streaming

Answer (score 0):

I have to use foreachBatch to transfer the structure stream to batch.